# please verify this code give me a suggestion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi this creates an error,
i neesd dynamic creation of rows and deletion please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Dynamic Rows</title>
  <script src="Include_Files/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("<table class='ta1' border='1'></table>").appendTo('.table1');
    $('.add').click(function(){
     addRows();
    };
function addRows(){
$table=$(".ta1");
$("<tr class='ta1'><td>rajasekhar</td><td>hostanalytics</td></tr>").appendTo($table); 
}
});
  </script>
   </head>
<body>
  <div id="table1"></div>
     <input type="button" class="add" name="add" value="AddRows"/>
     <input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" value="DeleteRows"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You just have a few syntactical errors, a missing `)` for your `.click()` handler mainly, and a `var` for `$table1`, so this:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
  addRows();
};
function addRows(){
  $table=$(".ta1");
  $("<tr class='ta1'><td>rajasekhar</td><td>hostanalytics</td></tr>").appendTo($table); 
}
```

Should be:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
  addRows();
});
function addRows(){
  var $table=$(".ta1");
  $("<tr class='ta1'><td>rajasekhar</td><td>hostanalytics</td></tr>").appendTo($table); 
}
```

And you can slim that down a bit further:

```
$('.add').click(addRows);
function addRows(){
  $("<tr class='ta1'><td>rajasekhar</td><td>hostanalytics</td></tr>").appendTo(".ta1"); 
}
```

Or just:

```
$('.add').click(function (){
  $("<tr class='ta1'><td>rajasekhar</td><td>hostanalytics</td></tr>").appendTo(".ta1"); 
});
```